# How to Dynamically creates a controls based on data in knockoutjs

Tags: html, knockout.js

My question is,
I am able to create a dynamic controls(textbox,label) based on data but I want to expected design in UI. Now I am facing the problem when manage the UI design.Please look at the design which is expected output.

```
  Lunch Start:01:00PM(textbox)         Lunch End:02:00PM(textbox)
  Lunch1 Start:04:00PM(textbox)        Lunch1 End:05:00PM(textbox)
```

When you see the above pattern there is `Lunch start,Lunch End,lunch1 start,lunch1 End` and soon.

I want to show the data dynamically over that controls.
Here is the VM list look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings({TIA: [{ type: 'Lunch Start', clocktime: '01:00 PM' },
            { type: 'Lunch End', clocktime: '02:00 PM' },{  type: 'Lunch1 Start', clocktime: '04:00 PM'  },{  type: 'Lunch1 End', clocktime: '05:00 PM'  }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Please somebody help to me how to manage this UI design as I expected in UI screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your VM around a little bit, so you just have one entry per line, which will make it easy to work with.

**VM**

```
var viewModel = { TIA: [{ description: 'Lunch', startTime: '01:00 PM', endTime: '02:00 PM' },
                        { description: 'Lunch1', startTime: '04:00 PM', endTime: '05:00 PM' }]
    };

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="foreach:TIA">
    <div>
        <label data-bind="text: description + ' Start'"></label>
        <input data-bind="value: startTime"></input>
        <label data-bind="text: description + ' End'"></label>
        <input data-bind="value: endTime"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can of course change around the html to suite your needs better, maybe you'll want to use a table instead, but this should give you and idea about how to get started. Test it out at http://jsfiddle.net/ptgoxssj/

Comment: Thank you another dev.
This code is working fine according to my scenario.

Comment: Great, you can accept the answer if it suites your needs.